# Camel CamelCreatedTimestamp exchange property

Tags: apache-camel, camel-spring-dsl

I am looking at some older Camel code where there are references to an Exchange property called **CamelCreatedTimestamp**. I believe I read a post that indicated that this property is no longer available as an Exchange property.

I've searched everywhere and cannot find much info on this property. Can anyone tell me what that property was\is and if there is a current direct replacement.If not, I need to understand the details of what that property ***use*** to contain.

The reason I ask is because I am looking at some sample code that does some date\time comparisons based on a value returned from **CamelCreatedTimestamp**. If this property is no longer available I shall need to build one with the exact same structure.

Thanks

Comment: A possible replacement would be to use the Simple language `${date:exchangeCreated}` expression - see https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/languages/simple-language.html

Comment: Thanks for info ...I am aware of good alternatives such as you suggest, however, without knowing what was in the original CamelCreatedTimestamp property, I will not know for certain if this is a good substitute.... I can guess\assume it was a LocalDateTime object but once again, this is just a guess.

Comment: According to the upgrade guide (https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-3x-upgrade-guide-3_1.html#_api_changes), the property `public static final java.lang.String CREATED_TIMESTAMP "CamelCreatedTimestamp"` "is no longer stored as exchange property, but you should use the getCreated method on Exchange"